# Python - data displaying incorrectly (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Im a newbie to python, i have a question. I am loading data from a CSV file, removing duplications, saving the removed duplications csv file, then loading the correct CSV files and generating the graph. My issue is however, the graphs are not being displyed correctly, as in the totals are wrong. I know the program is working correctly because if i remove section 1(please see below for #section1) i get the correct data being displayed. I cannot see what in Section 1 would be skewing the data... Any help would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Summary: Cannot run Section 1 and Section 2 in the same py file otherwise data is tallyed incorrectly. Wanting to know why? How to avoid it without running seperate py files.

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import csv
import itertools
```

## Section 1

```
 # Create database of duplicates - check if the mac and os pairs have     duplicates
reader = csv.reader(open('Workbook1.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')
writer = csv.writer(open('remacos.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
entries = set()

for row in reader:
key = (row[1], row[2])

if key not in entries:
    writer.writerow(row)
    entries.add(key)

entries.clear()
# Create database of duplicates - check if the mac and browser pairs     have duplicates
reader = csv.reader(open('Workbook1.csv', 'r'), delimiter=',')    
writer = csv.writer(open('remacbrowser.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')
entries = set()

for row in reader:
key = (row[1], row[3])

if key not in entries:
    writer.writerow(row)
    entries.add(key)
```

## Section 2

```
# Read Removed Duplicated entries Database and Count Values for OS.
df = pd.read_csv('remacos.csv', index_col="mac")         
counteros = Counter(df['os'])
os_names = counteros.keys()
os_counts = counteros.values()

# Read Removed Duplicated entries Database and Count Values for     Browsers.
df = pd.read_csv('remacbrowser.csv', index_col="mac")         
counterbrowsers = Counter(df['browser'])
browser_names = counterbrowsers.keys()
browser_counts = counterbrowsers.values()
```

Create 2 Bar graphs and a Pie Chart

```
# Plot histogram using matplotlib bar() for OS.
indexes = np.arange(len(os_names))
width = 0.7
plt.bar(indexes, os_counts, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, os_names)
plt.show()

# Plot histogram using matplotlib bar() for Browsers.
indexes = np.arange(len(browser_names))
width = 0.7
plt.bar(indexes, browser_counts, width)
plt.xticks(indexes + width * 0.5, browser_names)
plt.show()

# Make Pie Chart for OS's
plt.figure()
values = os_counts
labels = os_names
def make_autopct(values):
def my_autopct(pct):
total = sum(values)
val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
return '{p:.2f}%  ({v:d})'.format(p=pct,v=val)
return my_autopct
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=make_autopct(values))
#plt.pie(values, labels=labels) #autopct??
plt.show()
# Make Pie Chart for Browsers
plt.figure()
values = browser_counts
labels = browser_names
def make_autopct(values):
def my_autopct(pct):
total = sum(values)
val = int(round(pct*total/100.0))
return '{p:.2f}%  ({v:d})'.format(p=pct,v=val)
return my_autopct
plt.pie(values, labels=labels, autopct=make_autopct(values))
#plt.pie(values, labels=labels) #autopct??
plt.show()'
```

Comment: "the graphs are not being displyed correctly" is not a sufficient problem description. As you are saying that plotting works well when using the original file, the problem is related to "section1" and therefore all of "section2" is useless for this question. Instead, try to create a [MCVE], using only a couple of data lines in the csv file. Try to compare the output of "section1" with what you'd expect. Also, clearly state what you expect in the question and correct the code above for indentation in the for-loops.

Comment: This whole thing is the complete program, What I was trying to say was if I remove section 1 out of the .py file I get the graphs displaying the correct counts. When I include Section 1 I get lower counts if that makes sense. for example, HandHeld browser's count when displayd on the pie chart is 221 however the correct figure is 240, I get the correct figure if i remove section one from the script but Id like them both in the one script. So for some reason section 1 is skewing the counts

Answer (score -1):

Solution was to add 'del writer'after each Create database of duplicates